# How do I retrieve the session storage in Selenium (with Python)?

Tags: selenium

If you go to `https://www.google.com`, go into your browser's Developer Tools, and click on "`Storage -> Session Storage -> https://www.google.com`", you'll see three `key:value` pairs there:

```
_c;;i:"p:*|l:9007199254740991_2"

hsb;;1635503738313:"p:*|l:1_{"state":null,"url":"/","metadata":{"Nua":1635503738312,"Mj":1635503738313,"f6":1635503738314,"hz":0}}"

hsb;;1635503738314:"p:*|l:0_[1635503738313]"
```

How can you return those Session Storage values with a Selenium script?

`driver.execute_script("return sessionStorage.length")` returns 0, indicating that the values are not there.

Answer (score 0):

I had to read the session storage key value pairs using Selenium.
I tried the following commands for the Google webpage session variables and it worked perfectly fine
I did it on C# though
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string key = (string)js.ExecuteScript(“return sessionStorage.key(0)”);
string value = (string)js.ExecuteScript(“return sessionStorage.getItem(‘“ + key + “‘)”);

The key and value will have the values of the session variables that can be seen on the developer tools